# ActionMode with AppCompat can't change background and text colors

Tags: android, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionmode, actionmode

I'm trying to change the background and text colors for my ActionMode. I'm using API 11 and AppCompat.

I've tried it with the following style.xml, but the ActionMode background is always white and the text color is black.
I want to change text color to white and background color to blue.

How can I solve this?

Here is my style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- ActionMode -->
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionModeStyle</item>
    </style>


    <!-- Setup the style of the ActionMode here -->
    <style name="MyActionModeStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionModeTitle</item>

        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionModeTitle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Setup the text style of the ActionMode here -->
    <style name="MyActionModeTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In my Activity I'm using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity but I use toolbar:
Here is my settings_activity_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="@string/action_settings" />
```

Comment: did you try a `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>`?

Comment: Post your activity code too. I think I've found a workaround

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out, what is preventing textColor in ActionMode. I've succesfully changed the background color of ActionMode. Which version of AppCompat library are you using?

Comment: Which version of AppCompat are you using?. Check your build.gradle

Comment: It's   'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `android:actionModeStyle` too:

```
<item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionModeStyle</item>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because i've using API 11 and this is only avaiable in API 21?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I managed it by replacing the HomeAsUpIndicator programatically with an done button. Thats all I wanted...